# Opening large files with R, which don't fit in RAM

Tags: r, for-loop, data.table, large-files

I need to open, process, and merge 12 `.tsv` files, which are archived as `.bz2` files, but eventually my system runs out of memory before the below loop finishes. The total size of the archived files is 8GB and I am using a node with 120GB RAM.

I tried the following loop, which is heavily based on `data.table`. Any suggestions of how I can open, process, and merge these large files using R?

```
files <- list.files(path="/mypath", pattern="*.bz2", full.names=T, recursive=FALSE)

a <-data.table()
for(i in files) {
  print(i)
  dt <- fread(sprintf("bzcat %s | tr -d '\\000'", i), header=F)
  dt <- as.data.table(dt)

  dt$domain.ext <- domain(dt$ColA)
  help <- suffix_extract(dt$domain.ext)
  dt <- cbind(dt, help)
  rm(help)
  dt$domain.ext <- NULL 
  dt <- dt[ColB=="something",] 

  dt <- dt[,.(ColA, ColB, ColC, ColD, ColE)] 

  l = list(a,dt)
  rm(dt)
  a <- rbindlist(l, use.names = T, fill = F, idcol=NULL)
  rm(l)
  print(dim(a))
}

some more analysis using functions from data.table and urltools packages

save(a, file="all.RData", compress = "bzip2")
```

Comment: Take a look at `chunked` package - https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=chunked  It has dplyr backend for large text files out-of-memory processing.

Comment: Is 8GB the size of the archived files or the files of them decompressed? How big are they decompressed?

Comment: @GregoryDemin thank you. Does it mean that I will have to run my analysis to every chunk of the data?

Comment: @Hugh. Thank you. 8GB is the total size of the archived data. Decompressed are 67GB. I am now trying to first decompress the files and then run the above loop with `fread(i, header = F)` instead of decompressing on the fly with `bzcat`.

Comment: @et_ Yes, you will have to run your analysis by chunks. There is no straightforward method to fit 67Gb data to 8Gb of RAM so you are limited to out of the core algorithms which doesn't load all data to the memory at once. See, for example, biglm package for linear regression, Vowpal Wobbit etc.

Comment: fread all of the files at once by adding a glob to that top command and eliminate the for loop entirely. If that works memory wise you may get by step by step afterwords working on the entire table with care taken to modify by reference.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case it is helpful for somebody else, I realised that decompressing the `bz2` files within the `fread()` consumed too much RAM. So, my solution was to first decompress the `bz2` files and then run the above loop by replacing the `fread` line with the following one:

```
  dt <- fread(i, header=F)
```

Of course, I used much more hard drive space.